# How to install a new version GCC and make it the default?

Tags: software-installation, gcc, alternatives

I built and installed a new version of `gcc` on my Linux (Ubuntu) machine and installed it in `/opt/gcc-10.2.0`.

Then I used `update-alternatives` to make this the default `gcc`/`g++`.

It works, however, programs built with the new `gcc` still link to the old `libstdc++` in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` and not the one found in `/opt/gcc-10.2.0/lib64`.

This is a problem if the system's `libstdc++` uses the pre-C++11 ABI because this will cause the application to crash during startup.

Is there a way to install a newer version of GCC and make it the "default compiler" for the user and also ensure that  the programs built with it will link to the `libstc++` (and `libgcc`) bundled with that compiler?

I ask this because I want to create a build server that uses the most recent GCC version.

Comment: Could you specify what OS you are using? It would appear to be a Debian-based linux, but we would need to know.

Comment: Can you post the content of your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable?

Comment: 1) This is actually good since your compiled programs become more portable 2) You could try adding `-L/opt/gcc-10.2.0/lib64` to your compilations flags.

Comment: @AdminBee It's empty

Answer (score 0):

- This is actually good since your compiled programs become more portable.
- You could try adding `-L/opt/gcc-10.2.0/lib64` to your compilations flags.
- You could `sudo mkdir /usr/lib64/save; sudo mv -iv /usr/lib64/libstdc++* /usr/lib64/save` - this is not recommended.